# Update a document automatically based on a condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a set of documents stored in MongoDB, those objects look roughly like this (it's a simplified schema of an object)

```json
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  status: String,
  end_date: Date
}
```

(These objects can be updated many times after creation, so the `end_date` field can be changed, and it can be different for each object. They are also fetched from the database many times and are shown to users. Just so you know how they are used.)

How do I make sure that the `status` field is set to `expired` whenever `end_date` field is in the past compared to the current time? (all dates are in UTC) ?

I have got this snippet in JS

```js
myCollection.update({}, [
  {
    $set: {
      status: {
        $cond: [{ $lt: ["$end_date", "$$NOW"] }, "expired", "$status"],
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

Is it possible to set up a function like this on MongoDB side, which would run every minute?

What's the best solution for this task?

Comment: check [scheduled-triggers](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/triggers/scheduled-triggers/)

Comment: I did, it would work fine, thanks.